# How can I connect to a TLS Socket connect in a react native app

Tags: react-native, ssl, tcp, websocket, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to an SSL socket with a TLS 1.2 protocol. This is my code:

```
const client = new WebSocket('wss://<domain-name>');

client.onopen = () => {
    console.log('socket openend');      
};

this.client.onmessage = messageFunction;
this.client.onerror = errorFunction;
this.client.onclose = closeFunction;
```

And the connection closes immediately. I thought it may be due to the server not accepting my certificate so I used `react-native-cert-pinner` to pin all the relevant SHA256 pins, but still no luck.

For reference the following node.js code works, using the `tls` module:

```
const tls = require('tls');

const client = tls.connect({ host: '<domain-name>', port: 443 }, () => console.log('connected');
```

Any suggestions or insight into the issue would be greatly appreciated.